# jQuery trying to mask percentage using input mask

Tags: jquery, mask, jquery-inputmask

I have an input box for integer, float and percent and I am using jQuery input mask library for masking inputs. Everything is working fine except PERCENTAGE masking, please see below details

```
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/3.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>

<input type='text' id='var1' name='var1' value=''>

<input type='text' id='var2' name='var2' value=''>

<input type='text' id='var3' name='var3' value=''>
```

below is script i am using

```
$("#var1").inputmask({
        alias:"decimal",
        integerDigits:9,
        digits:2,
        allowMinus:false,
        digitsOptional: false,
        placeholder: "0"
});

$("#var2").inputmask({
       alias:"integer",
       integerDigits:9,
       digits: 0,
       allowMinus:false,
       digitsOptional: false,
       placeholder: "0"
});

 $("#var3").inputmask({
        alias:"numeric",
        integerDigits:3,
        digits: 0,
        max:100,
        allowMinus:false,
        digitsOptional: false,
        placeholder: "0"
 });
```

please help me for masking percentage

not working in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rikhi05/fwj3y4yb/4/)

Answer (score 1):

I use this and it work.

```
{
    alias: 'percentage'
}
```

I use version 3.3.4